# Different outputs from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two sql query outputs from a table , with orders..

One sql order directly from the table and the data is showing right, from last to first. 
But when i try the same way to show up the data but, this time I use a post method, so when click submit that data is being shown, but this time the showup begin from the first to the last query . Why is that.The mysql is simple just .

```
select * from smt order by smtorde
```

Comment: You will probably need to show more code

Answer (score 2):

You could also append the way you want the [MySQL Sort](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html) ordered with ASC or DESC

```
// Ascending 
select * from smt order by smtorde ASC

// Descending 
select * from smt order by smtorde DESC
```